# How to use after_action callback in rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a callback and there work fine in each method.

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController # :nodoc:
  def index
    @category = Category.friendly.find(params[:category_id])
    check_user_pro! if @category.id  == 3
  end

  def show
    @post =Post.find(params[:id])
    @category = @post.category
    check_user_pro! if @category.id  == 3
  end

  private


  def check_user_pro!
     if @current_user.present? && (is_not_an_admin! || !@current_user.profile.professional?)
     redirect_to(root_path)
  end
end
```

I would like to use a callback like :
`after_action :check_user_pro!, only: %i[index show] if -> {@category.id == 3}`

but this callback is alway call whatever is the category.id and I get this error : Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action

Comment: where is @rubrique defined in your code?

Comment: Sorry... It's a mistake I have updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot redirect or render in an after_action because the action has already rendered or redirected, what you can do instead is do a `before_action` which will redirect the request before it hits the action. It would look something like this:

```rb
class PostsController < ApplicationController # :nodoc:

  before_action :check_user_pro!, only: %i[index show], if: -> { category.id == 3 }

  def index
  end

  def show
    @post     = Post.find(params[:id])
    @category = @post.category
  end

  private

  def check_user_pro!
    redirect_to(root_path) if @current_user.present? && (is_not_an_admin! || !@current_user.profile.professional?)
  end

  def category
    @category ||= Category.friendly.find(params[:category_id])
  end

end
```